# What is the kernel of Mac Os

Tags: macos, operating-system, kernel

Linux is the kernel of Ubuntu like wise what is the kernel of Mac Os Which are using in apple laptops? are there any thing like that?

Answer (score 0):

Run uname -a  from the terminal to see your OS and machine details